# How to design xpages appLayout for 3 apps - each having 4 geographic instances

Tags: xpages

I built a prototype db using an appLayout that is working well with title bar tabs to 3 separate dbs. The prototype contains a setup document with server and filename for the 3 dbs. A SSJS library used by each xpage checks for a sessionScope variable. If null, it gets the locations of the 3 apps and sets 2 sessionScope variables used by all 3 data sources.  Now I need to add complexity so the 3 tabs will open the correct instance based on the user's geography. I need some help and assume others have done something similar.

My design thoughts are to...

1. Add a panel and a djFilteringSelect or ComboBox in the appLayout searchbar
2. Use CSJS and localStorage to get and set the geography
3. Store the geography in sessionScope.geography
4. Continue to use sessionScope variables for data source instance locations
5. Don't get geography from localStorage when opening every xpage, but get it only when sessionScope.geograhy is not set
6. Add a home/welcome page and display (redirect to) it instead of the initial db view xpage when sessionScope.geography is not set

I've been playing with this for several days unsuccessfully. I think I'm having issues with timing of events and passing values between CSJS and SSJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a session bean. Works like a session scope variable, but you have code that can execute when you do the `getDataDBLocation()` call (which in EL would be just `dataDBLocation`). You can entertain a number of strategies if that value isn't persisted:

- a name lookup into the NAB. Eventually a field there gives enough info on the location

  - a geodb lookup
  - a ping to all servers and use the fastest

if you also implement `setDataDBLocation(String location)` you can save a user preference back. The interesting point: the location you save doesn't need to be the value returned. So you do a `setDBLocation('Frankfurt')` but the `get` would return "server02!!europetasks.nsf"

Let us know how it works for you